# How to point a URL to a page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, .htaccess

I have seen in Wordpress, when you create a page say "Register", it points to http://example.com/register/ but without having a folder named register in the root at all. How is this done?

Its like this. When a user clicks the link on http://example.com/index.php which says Register, it takes the user to a new page and the URL in the browser would be http://example.com/register/ and the page loads. The `register` folder itself does not exist.

From the answers below I learnt that the request is passed through the index.php by modifying the `.htaccess`

I want to know what code to place in `index.php` so that http://example.com/register/ would display the register page.

Comment: see [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: using mod_rewrite in .htaccess to create a url like www.domain.com/index.php?page=register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Wordpress .htaccess file I have:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Which basically says if the "filename" part of the URL doesn't exist as a file `!-f` or exist as a directory `!-d` then rewrite the request internally to be `/index.php` which forces the request to be processed by `index.php` of Wordpress.

Ok, based on your additional comments, the following `.htaccess` rules will take `http://domain.com/<anything>` and internally rewrite it to `http://domain.com/index.php?page=<anything>`, this will be done without regard to case (`NC` flag) and will keep (pre-pend) any existing query string (`QSA` flag).  This only does this for filenames and directories that do not exist on the server.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This does have the following side effect which you should be able to handle programmatically, `http://domain.com/register/` will be rewritten to `http://domain.com/index.php?page=register/` which includes the trailing "/" since this is a directory reference.  Again, you should be able to handle that in your PHP code.

Comment: ok I got the .htaccess modification. please can you give me some hint what or how I could use the /register/ from the url to process n display the result?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to pass the string "register" to index.php as a part of the query string, such as `/index.php?u=register`?

Comment: what I mean to say is the I want the string "register" in a variable like $page so that I can give a condition like. if($page=="register") {} I guess I'll have to read the current url. That will do correct?

Comment: Can you add that to your question?  You need to include the name of the PHP file that you want to have executed, for example, do you want `http://bozo.com/register` to rewrite as `http://bozo.com/index.php?page=register`.

Comment: I've updated the question. what i mean to say is when http://domain.com/register/ is loaded, the url remains the same. but as you said, the request is passed through index.php, it must be the index.php that will show the content of `register` page on http://domain.com/register/

Comment: for example you can go to http://www.45royale.com/work/ the directory work doesnot exist but still the content is loaded by the index.php I want to know how that is done.

Comment: @NeilMartin Please see the update to my answer based on your additional questions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

When the web server, Apache in this case,  attempts to open a requested file path, `/register/` in this case, it first looks at the `.htaccess` file.

The `.htaccess` file among many other things can redirect the request to another path.

What usually happens is all requests redirect to a single file, `index.php` in WordPress, which reads the original request, `/register/`, and serves up the correct html.

What WordPress does to serve up the correct html is another question altogether but you can start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+wordpress+works

Comment: ok. I have a question. if there exists a file say `about.php` in the root, and if I access http://domain.com/about.php , will this request also be redirected to `index.php`? or only for those which result in an error?

Comment: @NeilMartin it depends how you set up the redirect in the `.htaccess` file. See @HeatfanJohn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses mod_rewrite in .htaccess file as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Which routes all page requests through index.php if the file or directory doesn't exist and the script is not index.php

Answer (score 0):

Neil Martin, this is really not a simple question. You are better off reading some good material on [URL REWRITING](http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/)

Comment: Yes. I did try reading about `.htaccess` files. I read a couple of tutorials. I did not find the answer. I got methods to redirect, deny folder access, etc. But not a method that spoke about this.